# Retry count and interval

Tags: javascript

How do I write script If a communication error is received, function shall by default, retry up to 3 times with a 15 second interval between re-tries. Whether a retry on a communication error is performed, the number of retries and the wait interval between tries shall be client configurable parameters. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to ask a good question. I would suggest you post at least the code of your best attempt to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a variable like `FailedCounts` and work with it.

Something like:

```
var failedCounts = 0, myInterval;

myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (operationFailed) {
    failedCounts++;
    if (failedCounts >= 3) {
      clearInterval(myInterval); // probably, you may want to disable timer on failure
      alert('Failed 3 times');
    }
  } else {
    failedCount = 0;
  }
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Good yr...but this will fix this for 3 retry and 15 sec. i wanna these parameters to be configured by client. how to do that?